# Display on 7-SEGMENT

Tags: c, microchip, pic24, seven-segment-display

I'm writing a code that displays temperature on the following 7 SEGMENT LCD:

[**LCD-H301C31TF Datasheet**](http://www.lumex.com/content/files/ProductAttachment/LCD-H301C31TR.pdf)

I'm using **PIC24FJ64GA006** Micro.

I can only use PORTB[13:6], PORTD[0:7], PORTE[0:7] port pins.

Can you help me find more elegant way to replace the following code?

```
void SegLCD_Set(uint8_t Value,uint8_t Digit)
{
    switch(Digit)
    {
        case 1:
            if(Value==0x00){ LATB = (LATB & ~(0x7F<<6)) | (0x3F<<6); }
            if(Value==0x01){ LATB = (LATB & ~(0x7F<<6)) | (0x0C<<6); }
            if(Value==0x02){ LATB = (LATB & ~(0x7F<<6)) | (0x5B<<6); }
            if(Value==0x03){ LATB = (LATB & ~(0x7F<<6)) | (0x5E<<6); }
            if(Value==0x04){ LATB = (LATB & ~(0x7F<<6)) | (0x6C<<6); }
            if(Value==0x05){ LATB = (LATB & ~(0x7F<<6)) | (0x76<<6); }
            if(Value==0x06){ LATB = (LATB & ~(0x7F<<6)) | (0x77<<6); }
            if(Value==0x07){ LATB = (LATB & ~(0x7F<<6)) | (0x1C<<6); }
            if(Value==0x08){ LATB = (LATB & ~(0x7F<<6)) | (0x7F<<6); }
            if(Value==0x09){ LATB = (LATB & ~(0x7F<<6)) | (0x7E<<6); }
            break;
        case 2:
            if(Value==0x00){ LATD = (LATD & ~(0xFF)) | (0x3F); }
            if(Value==0x01){ LATD = (LATD & ~(0xFF)) | (0x0C); }
            if(Value==0x02){ LATD = (LATD & ~(0xFF)) | (0x5B); }
            if(Value==0x03){ LATD = (LATD & ~(0xFF)) | (0x5E); }
            if(Value==0x04){ LATD = (LATD & ~(0xFF)) | (0x6C); }
            if(Value==0x05){ LATD = (LATD & ~(0xFF)) | (0x76); }
            if(Value==0x06){ LATD = (LATD & ~(0xFF)) | (0x77); }
            if(Value==0x07){ LATD = (LATD & ~(0xFF)) | (0x1C); }
            if(Value==0x08){ LATD = (LATD & ~(0xFF)) | (0x7F); }
            if(Value==0x09){ LATD = (LATD & ~(0xFF)) | (0x7E); }
            break;
        case 3:
            if(Value==0x00){ LATE = (LATE & ~(0xFF)) | (0x3F); }
            if(Value==0x01){ LATE = (LATE & ~(0xFF)) | (0x0C); }
            if(Value==0x02){ LATE = (LATE & ~(0xFF)) | (0x5B); }
            if(Value==0x03){ LATE = (LATE & ~(0xFF)) | (0x5E); }
            if(Value==0x04){ LATE = (LATE & ~(0xFF)) | (0x6C); }
            if(Value==0x05){ LATE = (LATE & ~(0xFF)) | (0x76); }
            if(Value==0x06){ LATE = (LATE & ~(0xFF)) | (0x77); }
            if(Value==0x07){ LATE = (LATE & ~(0xFF)) | (0x1C); }
            if(Value==0x08){ LATE = (LATE & ~(0xFF)) | (0x7F); }
            if(Value==0x09){ LATE = (LATE & ~(0xFF)) | (0x7E); }
            break;
        default:
            LATB = (LATB & ~(0x7F<<6)) | (0x3F<<6);
            LATD = (LATD & ~(0xFF)) | (0x3F);
            LATE = (LATE & ~(0xFF)) | (0x3F);
            break;
    };  

}//End SegLCD_Set
```

Thanks!

Comment: Learn how to use array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's any more elegant but this could work...

```
void SegLCD_Set(uint8_t Value,uint8_t Digit)
{
    unsigned char values[] = {0x3f, 0x0c, 0x5b, 0x5e, 0x6c, 0x76, 0x77, 0x1c, 0x7f, 0x7e};
     switch(Digit)
     {
     case 1:
         LATB = (LATB & ~(0x7F<<6)) | (values[Value]<<6);
         break;
     case 2:
         LATD = (LATD & ~(0xFF)) | (values[Value]);
         break;
     case 3:
         LATE = (LATE & ~(0xFF)) | (values[Value]);
         break;

     default:
         LATB = (LATB & ~(0x7F<<6)) | (0x3F<<6);
         LATD = (LATD & ~(0xFF)) | (0x3F);
         LATE = (LATE & ~(0xFF)) | (0x3F);
         break;
     };
}
```